# vector of smart pointer of class template

Tags: c++, templates, stl, smart-pointers

I try to use a `std::share_ptr` to replace the pointer inside a traditional `Node` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class Node
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr< Node<T> > Ptr;

public:
    T   data;

    std::vector< Node<T>::Ptr > childs;
};

int main()
{
    return 0 ;
}
```

However, it states that the input of `std::vector` is not a valid template type argument.

So the question is; How to make the class work, if I want to use a smart pointer of template class as the argument of STL container.

The error messages are (VS 2015)

```
Error   C2923   'std::vector': 'Node<T>::Ptr' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty' 
Error   C3203   'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type
```

[Editor]

Add head include files, and make them run-able.

Add error message

Comment: Shouldn't it be `std::vector<Ptr> childs;`? Seems to work with the correct includes: https://ideone.com/IzFJ75

Comment: You need `#include <memory>` and `#include <vector>`.  If this does not solve your problem please update the question to show the **exact** code that produces the error, and preferably also show the exact error message.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the error message verbatim

Comment: @mch in that scope there is no difference between `Ptr` and `Node<T>::Ptr`

Comment: @Obi hello. This is offtop but you can use this construction instead typedef.
"using Ptr =  std::shared_ptr< Node<T> >;"

Comment: @user463035818 you are right, but I like my version more, because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: @mch i would also prefer the shorter one, but I wouldnt tell someone else that they "should" do the same ;)

Comment: A word of warning (probably addressing your future, next question). Imagine you have a huge tree with the (fixed) code you have here... and it is destruction time. The destructor of the root node then calls the destructor of the ``childs`` vedtor which in turn calls the child nodes destructors and so forth until...depending on the depth of your tree... stack over flow! Yay - In honor to the name of this site. I did something similar with a list instead of a tree (shared pointers to link list nodes) and saw the stack overflow in action.

Comment: @mch Yes, if I use Ptr, it works.

Comment: @M.M and user463035818 I already put the complete code.

Comment: @BitTicker I have a generic tree (not binary) with about 10,000 nodes. The data type are variant and I want to use smart pointer instead of pointer (should I?). Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @user463035818 and mch, why Ptr works but not Node<T>::Ptr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct to me, at least it compiles (but does nothing) both on **gcc** and **clang**, no way to try vs2015 sorry, there is a chance that is not c++11 compliant?

Anyway here is a slightly expanded version of your code that do something (and shows how to use that shared_ptr you are trying to master):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>

template<class T>
class Node
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr< Node<T> > Ptr;

    T data;
    std::vector< Ptr > childs;

    void add_child(T data) {
        auto p = std::make_shared<Node<T>>();
        p->data = data;
        childs.push_back(p);
    }
    std::string dump(int level = 0) {
        std::ostringstream os;
        for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i) os << '\t';
        os << data << '\n';
        for (auto &c: childs) os << c->dump(level + 1);
        return os.str();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node<int> test;
    test.data = 1;
    test.add_child(2);
    test.add_child(3);
    std::cout << test.dump();
    return 0 ;
}
```